# Can solrcloud be running on a read-only filesystem?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We have a normal build/stage -> prod settings for our production pipeline. And we would build solr index in the build environment and then the index is copied to the prod environment.

The solrcloud in prod seems working fine when the file system backing it is writable. However, we see many errors when the file system is readonly. Many exceptions are thrown regarding the tlog file cannot be open for write when the solr nodes are restarted with the new data; some of the nodes eventually are stuck in the recovering phase and never able to go back online in the cloud.

Just wondering is anyone has any experience on Solrcloud running in readonly file system? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can get this to work without customizing parts of the codebase.

You already mentioned issues with the tlog, I suspect you would also find issues with the index locking (look [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/IndexConfig+in+SolrConfig#IndexConfiginSolrConfig-IndexLocks), apparently you would need to use *single* setting for read only).

IMHO, you should reconsider if you really need to run solrlcoud on a read only filesystem. If that is still the case:

- first go over the doc and tweak everything you can to better suit read only (like the locking above).
- then, start customizing part that are still failing (like the tlog) with your own version that works on a read only filesystem. This might not even be possible, or be possible only by making some features, like the tlog, a NOOP (that might be ok for your use case).